# decoding json object inside object inside object

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to decode json file using `json_decode()`, with second parameter `true` after the string of the json that i got from `file_get_contents()`. Like below.

```
json_decode(file_get_contents($dir), true);
```

I already make sure that the directory in file is correct and stored at `$dir` the json file is below.

```
{
"must": {
    "title": {
        "tag": "<!--section title-->",
        "content": null,
        "with-content": true
    },
    "class": {
        "tag": "<!--section class-->",
        "content": null,
        "with-content": true
    }
}
```

But when i try to fetch the json file using the script below.

```
if(is_file_ready($dir)) {
    $set = json_decode(file_get_contents($dir), true);
    echo file_get_contents($dir);   

    if(isset($set['must'])) {
        foreach($set['must'] as $node) {
        echo $node['tag'];
    }
}
```

It shows only the first `echo` like below, which the `echo $node['tag']` shows nothing.

> { "must": { "title": { "tag": "", "content": null, "with-content": true }, "class": { "tag": "", "content": null, "with-content": true } } }

When i change the `echo $node['tag']` to `print_r($node['tag'])` it shows like this.

> Array ( [tag] => [content] => [with-content] => 1 ) Array ( [tag] => [content] => [with-content] => 1 )

My question is why the `tag` returning `null` and the content too? are `<!-- -->` is readed as the comment at `json` same as `html`? or maybe something that i did wrong?

Thanks for any correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine. You just try to run it in your browser. If you open the dev tools (f12) you will see that in the html the values are displayed as comments so you don't see them.

If you use postman to run your script you will see that the output is printed normally.

[image]

Comment: Yup, you right my code are working fine, cause it became comment so i can't see it in normal browser, thanks for your explanation.